# Reading a local database created with MS access from a c#/ASP web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I am trying to connect and query a locally stored database from my c# code, here is what i have tried:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\\users\\alan\\desktop\\TestDatabase.mdb");
    con.Open(); 
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT MovieName FROM Movies;", con);
    OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
    var strValue = dr.GetString(0);
}
```

The problem is that when I get too var strValue = dr.GetString(0) it tells me no data exists for the row/column.
The database definetly exists and is being opened, there is definetly a tabled named Movies also, I just cant see why the query will not work. Any advice??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
 while (reader.Read())
        {
            var strValue =dr.GetString(0);
        }
```

**EDIT :**

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\\users\\alan\\desktop\\TestDatabase.mdb"))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT MovieName FROM Movies", connection);
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
        var strValue = dr.GetString(0);
           //or  var strValue = reader["MovieName"].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Still getting an error, but dr.Read() is returning true, this means there is something comin back from the query right??

Comment: @Alan select one column from query and try

Comment: Still saying no data exists for the row/column. There must be something wrong with the way the query is run.

Comment: @Alan Edited now try that

Comment: Thanks man this works, even with out the 'using' block, I cant see what the problem was but it works now at least :P